# Запуск IDE от JetBrains без плагинов

Tags: java, python, c++, ide, jetbrains

Можно ли запустить CLion/PyCharm/IDEA без включенных плагинов? Проблема в том, что один из плагинов не работаёт в новой обновлённой версии, и обычный запуск выдаёт ошибку:

> plugin X is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires
> build Y or older but the current build is Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываете папку `C:\Users\<Stuck>\.IntelliJIdea<версия>\config\plugins` и видите Ваши установленные плагины. Дальше либо просто удаляете нужный, если знаете имя или удаляете всё, предварительно записав на листик их названия.

Comment: Да, уже сделал что-то похожее, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Помог

1. сброс настроек до дефолтных (переименование директории CLion2020.3);
2. закрытие текущего открытого проекта, чтобы открылась новая менюшка с выбором проекта и плагинами;
3. возврат настроек (обратное переименование);
4. переименование директории плохого плагина;
5. обратное переименование директории плохого плагина.

Теперь появился файл `brokenPlugins.json`, который, видимо, не даёт запускать сломанный плагин.

Конкретно мой плагин `.ignore` можно пофиксить и вручную, как предлагают на его странице https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore/reviews, но чтобы IDE запустилось этого было недостаточно, надо было сбросить таки настройки/закрыть текущий проект.

> Please find folder *\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\idea-gitignore, open
> ./lib/idea-gitignore-3.2.3.202.jar and change "until-build" in
> /META-INF/plugin.xml, restart your IDEA.